# Trying to customize john rules, require at least one symbol in passwords

Tags: john-the-ripper

I"m trying to crack passwords that contains at least one symbol, e.g

```
qwe@123
```

I'm reading through the [cheat sheet here](https://countuponsecurity.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/jtr-cheat-sheet.pdf), didn't find anything relevant, does anyone know?